# Proguard is getting error and not building apk

Tags: android, android-proguard

```
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: proguard.ParseException: Unexpected keyword 'org.xmlpull.v1.**' in line 23 of file '/Users/arcpcarcpc/AndroidStudioProjects/SBSWI/spi-inspection/app/proguard-rules.pro'
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> Job failed, see logs for details
```

Comment: post your proguard rules for reflection

Comment: i have not use any rules

Comment: And the log output via Pastebin. There are usually some pointers from proguard in the error messages/warns.

Comment: then that might be your issue, do you use any 3rd party libraries

Comment: Warning:library class android.view.LayoutInflater depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser

Comment: what research have you done on ProGuard so far?

Comment: `i have not use any rules` error message says that you do.

Comment: thanks i remove that, but got another problem

Comment: Warning:library class android.view.LayoutInflater depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
Warning:there were 32 instances of library classes depending on program classes.
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> Job failed, see logs for details